# How do I connect a corporate VPN client such as Pritunl (OpenVPN) through another VPN tunnel such as Mullvad (WireGuard)?

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn, tunnel, wireguard

I'm on Windows 10 and 11. I use the Pritunl/OpenVPN client to connect to a corporate LAN.

At some point, the VPN stopped working. It won't connect. Maybe my ISP is blocking it, maybe my IP got blocklisted by the VPN server, maybe my router acts up. I am unable to fix it and I need a workaround.

I subscribed to Mullvad VPN and I tried connecting the Mullvad/WireGuard client and then the Pritunl/OpenVPN client. This works! Both clients connect successfully.

The problem is that I don't have access to any resources inside the corporate LAN. According to `tracert`, this seems to be because Mullvad routes all traffic through itself.

How do I make it work, preferably without messing with the route table?

Answer (score 1):

## TL/DR:

0. Subscribe to Mullvad VPN if you haven't already or set up a self-hosted WireGuard server.
1. Use the vanilla [WireGuard client](https://www.wireguard.com/install/).
2. [Export](https://mullvad.net/en/help/wireguard-app-windows/) a server configuration from Mullvad.
3. Update the `AllowedIPs` property to exclude LAN IP ranges.
4. Add your corporate intranet DNS server to the `DNS` property.
5. Update the `InterfaceMetric` of your connections.

## 0. Subscribe to Mullvad VPN if you haven't already or set up a self-hosted WireGuard server

Mullvad VPN: https://mullvad.net/en

Setting up a self-hosted WireGuard VPN server is wa-a-ay out of scope of this guide. But I was able to do it using this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-wireguard-on-ubuntu-22-04

## 1. Use the vanilla WireGuard client

The Mullvad VPN client does not allow configuring `AllowedIPS` or `DNS`. Their tech support recommend using the vanilla WireGuard client, but they refuse to assist configuring it. Don't worry, we got you covered!

Download the vanilla WireGuard client here:
https://www.wireguard.com/install/

## 2. Export a server configuration from Mullvad and import it to the WireGuard client

Visit this link for instructions:
https://mullvad.net/en/help/wireguard-app-windows/

After log in, configuration exporting is available here:
https://mullvad.net/en/account/#/wireguard-config/?platform=windows

Please note that you don't have to export all servers as the manual suggests. Pick just one server for starters, the one that the Mullvad client chooses by default (hopefully it's one of the fastest for you).

Import the configuration to the WireGuard client.

## 3. Update the `AllowedIPs` property to exclude LAN IP ranges.

This is the tricky part.

The `AllowedIPs` configuration property name is misleading. What it actually does is defines which IP ranges should be routed through the WireGuard VPN connection. Ranges that are not covered will work directly, outside the VPN.

The problem is that you don't want to allow ranges, you want to exclude ranges! Specifically, you need to exclude all the LAN subnets such as `10.x.x.x`, `172.16.x.x` and `192.168.x.x`.

In order to do that, you need to specify all ranges between and around those LAN ranges, which is not a trivial task at all.

Luckily, there exist online calclators that do this for you. I googled up this one:
https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2021/03/wireguard-allowedips-calculator/

I input the following ranges:

- Allowed IPs: `0.0.0.0/0`
- Disallowed IPs: `10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16`

And press <kbd>Calculate</kbd>. The result is:

```
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/5, 8.0.0.0/7, 11.0.0.0/8, 12.0.0.0/6, 16.0.0.0/4, 32.0.0.0/3, 64.0.0.0/2, 128.0.0.0/3, 160.0.0.0/5, 168.0.0.0/6, 172.0.0.0/12, 172.32.0.0/11, 172.64.0.0/10, 172.128.0.0/9, 173.0.0.0/8, 174.0.0.0/7, 176.0.0.0/4, 192.0.0.0/9, 192.128.0.0/11, 192.160.0.0/13, 192.169.0.0/16, 192.170.0.0/15, 192.172.0.0/14, 192.176.0.0/12, 192.192.0.0/10, 193.0.0.0/8, 194.0.0.0/7, 196.0.0.0/6, 200.0.0.0/5, 208.0.0.0/4, 224.0.0.0/3
```

This is the range of all IPs *except* LAN subnets.

Edit your server ("tunnel") in the WireGuard app and put this line into the `[Peer]` section.

Note that you can use the calculator to exclude more IP addresses from the VPN to access them directly.

## 4. Add your corporate intranet DNS server to the `DNS` property.

You need to know which DNS server the corporate intranet is using.

To find it out with a working corporate connection (ask your colleague?), use the follwing **while the corporate VPN is connected and intranet resources are accessible**.

#### On Windows:

```
nslookup <corporate.resource.local>
```

The output will look like this:

> ❯ nslookup coroprate.resource.local
>
> Server:  ip-10-2-0-2.eu-central-1.compute.internal
> Address:  **10.2.0.2**
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
> Name:    internal-blah-blah.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com
> Addresses:  10.2.3.4                                                                        >            10.3.4.5
> Aliases:  corporate.resource.local

#### On POSIX (in case your colleague uses MacOS or Linux):

```
dig <coroprate.resource.local>
```

> ❯ dig coroprate.resource.local
>
> ; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> coroprate.resource.local
> ;; global options: +cmd
> ;; Got answer:
> ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 32760
> ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
>
> ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
> ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
> ;; QUESTION SECTION:
> ;coroprate.resource.local.               IN      A
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION:
> coroprate.resource.local.        49      IN      CNAME   internal-garble-garble.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com.
> internal-garble-garble.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com. 36 IN A 10.34.9.140
> internal-garble-garble.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com. 36 IN A 10.34.8.128
>
> ;; Query time: 50 msec
> ;; SERVER: **10.2.0.2**#53(10.2.0.2)
> ;; WHEN: Wed Apr 05 11:53:23 MSK 2023
> ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 156

Copy the IP address of the intranet DNS server (it's in bold in above examples) and paste it into the WireGuard server (tunnel) configuration, into the `DNS` proeprty under the `[Interface]` section, prepending the existing DNS IP address, separated by a space:

```
DNS = 10.2.0.2 10.64.0.1
```

Note: if you're using WSL, it will not use the corporate DNS server. Follow this QA to figure it out:
[How do I change the DNS settings for WSL2?](https://superuser.com/q/1533291/200497)

## 5. Update the `InterfaceMetric` of your connections.

Finally, the priority of your corporate VPN interface must be higher than that of WireGuard. To achieve that, you need to make the corporate `InterfaceMetric` smaller than that of WireGuard.

You can edit the `InterfaceMetric` in the Advanced settings of the TCP/IP stack of your VPN interface:

[image]

But I prefer to do it in the terminal.

Start PowerShell **as an administrator** and run this command:

```
Get-NetIPInterface | Sort-Object Interfacemetric
```

In the output, find your corporate VPN interface and WireGuard and compare their `InterfaceMetric` (fragment shown):

```
> Get-NetIPInterface | Sort-Object Interfacemetric

ifIndex InterfaceAlias                  AddressFamily NlMtu(Bytes) InterfaceMetric Dhcp     ConnectionState PolicyStore
------- --------------                  ------------- ------------ --------------- ----     --------------- -----------
27      VPN - VPN Client                IPv4                  1500               1 Enabled  Disconnected    ActiveStore
54      Pritunl 1                       IPv6                  1500              25 Enabled  Disconnected    ActiveStore
53      se-sto-wg-011                   IPv4                  1420              10 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
```

There may be duplicate entries, don't worry about that.

The `InterfaceMetric` of the coroprate VPN interface must be lower than that of WireGuard.

If it's not, use this command to update `InterfaceMetric`s:

```
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex <ifIndex> -InterfaceMetric <value>
```

I set the corporate value to 3 and WireGuard to 5.

## Success!

You're done! Connect WireGuard first, then the corporate VPN. You should have access now.